# using setOnItemClickListener to delete an entry from listview

Tags: android

I have a listview and I want to able to select one of the entries here in order to delete it. For example, my entry in listview looks like this:

John Smith

john@hotmail.com

4857394

NewYork

So I want to select this one and delete it. I find this set OnItemClickListener in order to select it. I have delete function. I just need to select name "John Smith" when I click this entry. I don't know what I can write inside function here.

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
    {       
        listContent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

    listContent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    listContent.removeViewAt(position);
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();========> your adapter

}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may remove an item as below:

```
adapter.remove(listContent.getAdapter().getItem(arg2));
```

**Note**: Since you are removing directly from adapter object, so you don't need to worry about calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` method for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

On ListView you are providing data through some collection of data and index of individual data in list will be same as it is shown in screen. So onItemClick method you are also getting int arg2 , which signifies selected list. Same index you can use to delete element from List and write this deletion operations in runOnUIThread method so that you will not find any glitches.